# get list of active employees at a store

Tags: mysql

I have a table with data of employees and where they worked and how much they sold. These employees tend to move around from store location every couple of months.

Sometimes when a employee moves some of his sales still get credited to the old sales location due to business reasons.

Here is a snapshot of the data:

```
location_id    | employee_id  | name    |  unit_sold  | month 
2              | abc          | john    |12           | 3
1              | abc          | john    |1            | 3
5              | rst          | bob     |11           | 2
2              | qwe          | tim     |12           | 3
1              | gsd          | jim     |1            | 3
1              | uio          | joe     |11           | 3
1              | abc          | john    |50           | 1
```

So notice that John has worked at 2 locations in month 3. On location=1 he sold 1 item and location=2 he sold 12. His actual place of employement is the location that has the higher unit_sold for the latest queried month. Also notice that John sold 50 units in month one at location =1 but that is not his work location in month=3.

Here is what my query needs to do:

Get a list of all current employees that work at location =? during time range x to y.

Current means that they must still be active in the latest month. Also if an employee has worked at more that one location during the latest month of the time range then he should only be included if the location being queried was the place he sold the most units that month.

Here is my try so far.

```
SELECT 
  employee_id,
  NAME 
FROM
  mytable 
WHERE location_id = '1' 
  AND month BETWEEN '1' 
  AND '3' 
  AND (employee_id, `month`, location_id) IN 
  (SELECT 
    employee_id,
    `month`,
    location_id 
  FROM
    mytable 
  WHERE month BETWEEN '1' 
    AND '3') 
GROUP BY employee_id
```

It returns order employees as well in the response.

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8dcd/2)

Comment: `BETWEEN` range should be ascending.

Comment: thanks @raina77ow i update my query so that `between` range is ascending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what is working. Check the SQL Fiddle in the question.

Need to highly optimise this.

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM mytable 
      WHERE `month` = 3 
      ORDER BY `month` DESC,
      units_sold DESC) a 
  GROUP BY employee_id) j 
WHERE location_id = 1
```